# Array of Structs | Not passing values

Tags: c#, struct

I am new to structs in C# and I am stuck and can not pass the values in a file back to struct and successfully read them again.

The initialisation values work fine, but the file will not load at all

This is what I have so far:

```
    public struct Card
    {
        public char suit;//'C'- Clubs, 'D'-Diamonds,'H'- Hearts
        //and 'S'- Spades

        public int value;//2-14 – for 2-10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const int CARDS_IN_HAND = 5;//number of cards in hand

        Card[] hand = new Card[CARDS_IN_HAND];//array of cards

        InitialiseArray(hand);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Initialised Values in Array");
        DisplayHandData(hand);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The issue seems to be below

```
        LoadArray(hand);//load values into array for use

        //check values loaded to array
        Console.WriteLine("-------------\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Actuals Values in Array from file");
        DisplayHandData(hand);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static void InitialiseArray(Card[] data)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < data.Length; count++)
        {
            data[count].suit = 'C';
            data[count].value = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void LoadArray(Card[] data)
    {
        string fileName = "FullHouse.txt";//name of file for menu item 3
        //data in file = C 13 H 13 D 13 C 10 H 10
        string input = fileName;

        List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
        //string input = fileName;

        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fileName);//open file
        input = inFile.ReadLine();//priming read for array

        string[] inputArray = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //input loading data into array
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
        {
            Card newCard = new Card();
            newCard.suit = inputArray[i][0];
            newCard.value = int.Parse(inputArray[i + 1]);
            cards.Add(newCard);
        }
        inFile.Close();
    }

    public static void DisplayHandData(Card[] data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        //test values loaded into array in correct positions
        for (int records = 0; records < data.Length; records++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[records].suit);
            Console.WriteLine(data[records].value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-------------\n");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be from a C background. Instead of using a char for the types of cards, consider using an enum.

Comment: Do you have an example on how this would look?

Comment: You can read about enums at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LoadArray` should work just fine. The problem is probably that you are filling in variable `cards`, which is a local `List<Card>`, but what you probably want to do is fill in the `data` parameter.

Here is my sugestion for altering the `for`-cycle in `LoadArray` method

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
{
    Card newCard = new Card();
    newCard.suit = inputArray[i * 2][0];
    newCard.value = int.Parse(inputArray[i * 2 + 1]);
    data[i] = newCard;
}
```

But be careful about this approach. It is quite fragile. If there will be a mismatch in the length of `data` and `inputArray`, you will get an exception (if `inputArray` will be shorter than expected). You should check the length before the `for`-cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your LoadArray() method isn't changing the contents of the array passed in to it.

I recommend using a List in your main method instead, and change `LoadArray()` to:

```
public static List<Card> LoadArray()
{
    string fileName = "FullHouse.txt";//name of file for menu item 3
    //data in file = C 13 H 13 D 13 C 10 H 10
    string input = fileName;

    List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
    //string input = fileName;

    StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fileName);//open file
    input = inFile.ReadLine();//priming read for array

    string[] inputArray = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //input loading data into array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
    {
        Card newCard = new Card();
        newCard.suit = inputArray[i][0];
        newCard.value = int.Parse(inputArray[i + 1]);
        cards.Add(newCard);
    }
    inFile.Close();

    return cards;
}
```

Then you shouldn't need the `InitialiseArray()` method at all.

Instead you can do:

```
var hand = LoadArray();
```

Of course, then you might want to rename `LoadArray()` to something like `LoadHand()`.

Comment: thank you Matthew, I am stuck on how to check the values returned to 'var hand'. in the main, sorry I am new to c#

Answer (score 0):

You can check, the value using `Console.WriteLine(hand.Count)` this will give you the size, and you can display your data in `hand` some like this

```
foreach(var h in hand)
{
   Console.WriteLine(h.suit);
   Console.WriteLine(h.value);
}
```

if you wish you can try this too.

```
hand.ForEach(h=> 
{
   Console.WriteLine(h.suit);
   Console.WriteLine(h.value);
});
```

**Edited**:
Sorry, Matthew; I should put this as a comment under your answer. :-)